# Acumatica - Composite primary key

Tags: acumatica, master-detail

There is master-child table and master record has composite key on OrderNbr and RevisionNbr,
On UI we want to present the Selector for both the fields 
OrderNbr with Max Revision number for Order number selector
Revision Number selector based on order Number selected ON UI.

also on UI we have function to create New revision, How we can create revision by Code, I am getting error of MUlti part query, when I defined IsKey= true for both the fields and tried to Save the data By

```
Graph.primaryView.Insert()
ForEach(UIRow){
      Graph.ChildView.Insert
}
Graph.Persist();
```

Note the MAster table has Identity column in the SQL server has Key

Update-
Parent Table DAC -

```
#region TestSuiteID
public abstract class testSuiteID:PX.Data.IBqlField {
}
protected int? _TestSuiteID;
[PXDBIdentity()]
public virtual int? TestSuiteID {
  get {
    return this._TestSuiteID;
  }
  set {
    this._TestSuiteID = value;
  }
}
#endregion
#region TestSuiteCD
public abstract class testSuiteCD:PX.Data.IBqlField {
}
protected string _TestSuiteCD;
[PXDBString(50, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
[PXDefault()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Test Group ID")]
[PXSelector(typeof(EWQCTestSuite.testSuiteCD), typeof(EWQCTestSuite.testSuiteCD), typeof(EWQCTestSuite.revisionNo), typeof(EWQCTestSuite.name))]
public virtual string TestSuiteCD {
  get {
    return this._TestSuiteCD;
  }
  set {
    this._TestSuiteCD = value;
  }
}
#endregion
#region RevisionNo
public abstract class revisionNo:PX.Data.IBqlField {
}
protected int? _RevisionNo;
[PXDBInt(IsKey=true)]
[PXDefault(1)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Revision No")]
public virtual int? RevisionNo {
  get {
    return this._RevisionNo;
  }
  set {
    this._RevisionNo = value;
  }
}
#endregion
```

Child Table Dac -

```
#region TestSuiteVariableID
public abstract class testSuiteVariableID:PX.Data.IBqlField {
}


protected int? _TestSuiteVariableID;
[PXDBIdentity(IsKey = true)]
public virtual int? TestSuiteVariableID {
  get {
    return this._TestSuiteVariableID;
  }
  set {
    this._TestSuiteVariableID = value;
  }
}
#endregion

#region TestSuiteID
public abstract class testSuiteID:PX.Data.IBqlField {
}
protected int? _TestSuiteID;
[PXDBInt()]
[PXDBDefault(typeof(EWQCTestSuite.testSuiteID))]
[PXParent(typeof(Select<EWQCTestSuite, Where<EWQCTestSuite.testSuiteID, Equal<Current<EWQCTestSuite.testSuiteID>>>>))]
public virtual int? TestSuiteID {
  get {
    return this._TestSuiteID;
  }
  set {
    this._TestSuiteID = value;
  }
}
#endregion
```

Note - Child table does not have MAster tab CD and revision number column as I added Identity column fr reference and have PXParent with Identity column.
Both Dac has other fields that I have not added here.

Other issue that I am facing is When I am Deleting the record I am getting some Primarykey reference error (Delete by default acumatica delete button on Primary DataView)

Comment: you should include the important fields as you have them defined in your dac. Do you have a PXDBDefault on your child table pointing to the parent fields? do you have a PXParent setup on the child record? You should avoid an identity column when you have multiple keys on a table (although should work). Use a numbering sequence field vs identity column. For the selector you can use a PXProjection on the child table to just get a max revision order by ordernbr and use that in your selector. I can try to do a real answer later but some things to consider for now

Comment: Thanks,
You mean I should include the OrdNbr and Revision number fields in child table also, although I have OrderID already defined for Parent Child relationShip?

Yes I have [PXDBDefault]  with OrderID on child table
I used [PXParent] on child dac with OrderID field

Comment: I think he means you should add more details (code) to your question. My answer is very generic because there's not much information in your question.

Comment: I Updated My original Post, Please check the DAC code

Comment: i was referring to the need for a multi part key when you are using an identity field since each insert to the table will already be unique there is no need for more than one key. ideally would just be the Identity field or if needing a pair you could use a numbering sequence field with another field such as revisionno. But PXDBDefault and PXParent should be all you need on the children. Also multi part keys with the default navigation sometimes are not the easiest to get working in an Acumatica page. We have a custom PXGraph to work with these dual key (2 strings) pages.

Comment: HI,
I am using the Multi Part key as it was suggested in the T200 to use Identity column as surrogate key and CD columns as actual key in the graph and second In selection I want to show CD value and revision value not the ID column value as user is not suppose to add ID

Comment: if using an ID/CD field in your DAC yes an identity column would work but in that scenario i would think there is still only 1 key. (For example InventoryItem for InventoryID and InventoryCD). When using Acuminator it will also point out the recommendation of using an Identity column as the only key in the DAC/Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For composite key ..Instead of using PXGraph use PXRevisionableGraph.
This graph is part of manufactoring module and supports composite key..
All your key should be decorated with attribute inherited by AcctSubAttribute

Answer (score 0):

The multi-part query error is usually related to a master-detail (parent-child) query that resolves to more than one parent when executed. The child DAC should have a PXParent attribute that includes where clause on all the key fields.

```
[PXParent(typeof(Select<Master,
                 Where<Master.key1, Equal<Current<Child.key1>>,
                 And<Master.key2, Equal<Current<Child.key2>>>>>>))]
```

You should make sure all BQL queries  in the DAC and the Graph that have such a relationship include a where filter or on join clause on all keys. Also make sure all key fields in DAC have `IsKey=true` and that the matching database fields where created as key fields in the database.

Comment: Hi,My set up is IN DB Parent table has Identity Column as Key 
OrderID
in DAC I have OrdNumber and Revision number as Cache Key by using ISKey=True attribute

My Child Table uses OrderID field with [PXParent] attribute to define master child relationship with the Select caluse on OrderID

Comment: Please verify that your use of Current in the PXParent attribute identifies the Child DAC and not the Master DAC... currently you show Master; should it be Current<EWQCTestSuiteVariable.testSuiteID> ?

Comment: Hi John,
Yes this was typo in the Posted code here,
I used  [PXParent(typeof(Select<EWQCTestSuiteVariable, Where<EWQCTestSuiteVariable.testSuiteID, Equal<Current<EWQCTestSuite.testSuiteID>>>>))]

Comment: Please try:  [PXParent(typeof(Select<EWQCTestSuite, Where<EWQCTestSuite.testSuiteID, Equal<Current<EWQCTestSuiteVariable.testSuiteID>>>>))]